# Cannot run spray examples

Tags: scala, sbt, spray

I am starting a project with spray, and try to follow their wiki in order to run their example application (to start my project on them).
However, I cannot have them working, it seems that the sbt configuration of spray has changed quite a lot since this documentation was written.

The [instructions](https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/Example-Projects) do not work for me when I `sbt "project spray-example-simple" shell` I got rejected like this:

```
~/.../spray/project # sbt "project spray-can-examples" shell

[info] Set current project to default-951202 (in build file:/home/jolivier/projects/external/spray/project/)
[error] Not a valid project ID: spray-can-examples
[error] project spray-can-examples
[error]                           ^
```

Although `Build.scala` (in the same folder), contains a project with this name:

```
  lazy val examples = Project("examples", file("examples"))
    .aggregate(sprayCanExamples, sprayClientExamples, sprayIoExamples, sprayServerExamples)
    .settings(exampleSettings: _*)

  lazy val sprayCanExamples = Project("spray-can-examples", file("examples/spray-can"))
    .aggregate(simpleHttpClient, simpleHttpServer)
    .settings(exampleSettings: _*)
```

So I'm quite disturbed on why I am rejected by sbt. I tried running the `sbt project` command on several other folders like `examples` but got the same error. What am I missing? I'm quite disturbed by the the `Set current project to default-951202`, this does not look good to me but I don't know how to fix that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to run sbt from the cloned repo. root:

```
spray> sbt11 "project spray-can-examples" shell
```

`spray` is the folder where I cloned the repo. Here sbt11 invokes `sbt-launch-0.11.2.jar`.

It worked just fine.

Comment: [warn] ==== spray repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.spray.io/com/decodified/scala-ssh/0.6.2/scala-ssh-0.6.2.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.decodified#scala-ssh;0.6.2!scala-ssh.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.decodified#scala-ssh;0.6.2!scala-ssh.jar